# Listbox that can 'snap'

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I'm making a Windows Phone application that needs a listbox that can "snap" to positions as it scrolls (just like the one in the Media Hub that shows current/future songs).

I've spent awhile looking all over google and can't find anything. Is there a native control that does it, or a third party library that contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built in controls that do this.
The `SlideView` from the [Telerik RadControls](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) can do this.

It's $99 or free if you sign up for the [Nokia Premium Developer Program](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Developer_Programs/Premium_program.xhtml) rather than sign up with the App Hub directly.

Comment: I already have Telerik's WP RadControls. Thanks for the heads up.